# instanceof operator returns false on subsequent change to inheritance chain

Tags: javascript, prototype

When a prototype is set on a constructor function, the `instanceof` operator only returns `true` until the prototype is changed. Why?

```
function SomeConstructorFunction() {
}

function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn) {
    constructorFn.prototype = {}; //Can be any prototype
    return new constructorFn();
}

var child1 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true

var child2 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //false
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototypal inheritance can be a bit of a brain bender. I've already written a simple explanation for prototypal inheritance in the following answer and I suggest you read it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096017/783743

Now to answer your question. Consider the following function:

```
function F() {}
```

I can create an instance of `F` using `new` as follows:

```
var f = new F;
```

As expected `f instanceof F` returns `true`. This is because the `instanceof` operator checks for `F.prototype` in the prototype chain of `f` and returns `true` if it is there. See the answer I linked to above.

Now say I create a new function `G` as follows and set `F.prototype` to `G.prototype`:

```
function G() {}

F.prototype = G.prototype;
```

If I now evaluate `f instanceof F` again `false` is returned. This is because `F.prototype` is no longer in the prototype chain of `f` (remember that `F.prototype` is now `G.prototype`).

Now let's create a new instance of `F`:

```
var g = new F;
```

If you evaluate `g instanceof G` it'll return `true` even though `g = new F`. This is because `G.prototype` exists in the prototype chain of `g`.

This is not a bug. It's the way JavaScript works. In fact we can exploit this feature to create some really interesting functions: [Instantiate JavaScript functions with custom prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11490606/783743)

Comment: Great explanation of prototypal inheritance. I think that OP's confusion lies in `constructorFn.prototype = {}; //Can be any prototype`. He's expecting that setting the prototype to the same **value** will result in `instanceof` being true, when instead, they should be set to the same **reference**.

Comment: @MattDiamant - I agree. I don't know what the OP is trying to accomplish using `extendAndInstantiate` but I believe it's a bit like my own `instantiate` function in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11490606/783743

Comment: Good explanation. Most importantly, I was missing the fact that setting the prototype to `{}` effectively changes the type of `SomeConstructorFunction` to `Object`. `SomeConstructorFunction.constructor` is `function Object...`.

Answer (score 3):

```
constructorFn.prototype = {}; //Can be any prototype
```

Not true!

```
constructorFn.prototype = Object.prototype;
```

Or any other native prototype will make them all true.

The reason is that the first time that you're calling `extendAndInstantiate()`, you're setting the SomeConstructorFunction's prototype to something (here an empty object `{}`). For `child1`, instanceOf will only return true while SomeConstructorFunction's prototype **is that exact instance of `{}`**. When you run `extendAnInstantiate()` a second time, you're changing `SomeConstructorFunction`'s prototype to a different instance of `{}`, so `child2` will be an instanceOf that new `{}`, but `child1` is still an instanceOf of the old `{}`, so `child1` will return false, while `child2` returning true. If you set the prototype to a common prototype, such as `Object.prototype` or `Array.prototype`, it will always return true.

Another way to illustrate this is to pull `{}` out of the function, and assign it to a variable `obj`.

```
var obj = {};
function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn) {
    constructorFn.prototype = obj;
    return new constructorFn();
}
```

Now this will always return true, because you aren't creating a new `{}` every time you run the function.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is based on the prototype object.

```
function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn) {
constructorFn.prototype = {}; //Can be any prototype
...
```

When you set the prototype to {} you're creating a new object and setting it as the prototype.  Because it is then not the same object as the prototype, `instanceof` returns false.

A setup like this will return true for all cases, because the prototype will be the same object:

```
function SomeConstructorFunction() {
}

var emptyObj = {};

function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn) {
    constructorFn.prototype = emptyObj; 
    return new constructorFn();
}

var child1 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true

var child2 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you  call `extendAndInstantiate` a new object is created using `{}` and it is assigned as the prototype of `SomeConstructorFunction`. This clears the link between existing instances and `SomeConstructorFunction`. So only final one will be a valid instance of `SomeConstructorFunction`.

```
function SomeConstructorFunction() {

}

function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn) {
  constructorFn.prototype = {}; //New instance as prototype
    return new constructorFn();
}

var child1 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true

var child2 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //false
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true


var child3 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //false
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //false
console.log(child3 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
```

So either you can follow the method showed by @ben336 or do a condition check before assigning prototype as shown below.

```
function Base(){

}

function SomeConstructorFunction() {

}

function extendAndInstantiate(constructorFn, Base) {
  if(!(constructorFn.prototype instanceof Base)){
    console.log(" extend only once ");
    constructorFn.prototype = new Base(); 
  }
  return new constructorFn();
}


var child1 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction, Base);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true

var child2 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction, Base);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true


var child3 = extendAndInstantiate(SomeConstructorFunction, Base);
console.log(child1 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
console.log(child2 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
console.log(child3 instanceof SomeConstructorFunction); //true
```