# How to clone a constructor in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor `Monkey()`:

```
function Monkey(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

I want to make another constructor named `Human()` with an extra property `cars` which will store number of cars the person has along with all the property that `Monkey` has *(like `name` and `age`)*

I don't want to repeat all the `Monkey` stuff in the new `Human` stuff. Is is possible to clone the `Monkey` and extend a property with *prototype*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried this code, I guess it's what you want:

```
function Human(name,age,cars){
    Monkey.call(this,name,age);
    this.cars = cars;
}
```

This way, the `Human` constructor calls the `Monkey` constructor as a normal function, but setting its namespace as the new `Human` object. Thus, in this case, the `this` keyword inside `Monkey` constructor refers to a object of class `Human`, and not `Monkey.` Also, with this code, the condition `new Human() instanceof Human;` returns `true`, since I'm not returning a new instance of `Monkey`, just using its constructor.

Also, you can "clone" the prototype, as you said. Just do this:

```
Human.prototype = Monkey.prototype;
```

**EDIT**

As @Bergi amd suggested, the best way to clone a prototype is using the [Object.create method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), as follows:

```
Human.prototype = Object.create(Monkey.prototype, {constructor:{value:Human}});
```

Comment: `Human.prototype = Object.create(Monkey.prototype, {constructor:{value:Human}});` would be better, else all monkeys are `instanceof Human` and `(new Human).constructor` would be monkey.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, I didn't know about it. I will update the answer

Comment: Actually, you should do both - then you get the methods on the prototype and the side-effects of the constructor. (Or what @Bergi said, but if `Object.create` isn't supported, then it's `Human.prototype = new Monkey(); Human.prototype.constructor = Human;`.)

Comment: @minitech: I'm sure it was meant to be both. Btw, you should *not* use `Human.prototype = new Monkey` - you're getting the side effects of the constructor where they are not applicable. There are better ways to shim [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I just meant in this particular case, since the constructor doesn't do anything except set properties.

Comment: Also note that `Human.prototype = Monkey.prototype` does not in any way "clone" the prototype object, it just means `Human.prototype` references `Monkey.prototype`, there is one object and no "clone".

Answer (score 0):

Simple start for functional style/parasitic'ish inheritance:

```
function Human(name, age, cars) {
  var that = new Monkey(name, age);
  that.cars = cars;
  return that;
}
```

As outlined by Douglas Crockford

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: Yes, but this way the constructor returns an object of type `Monkey`, and not of `Human` (see `new Human() instanceof Human;`)

Comment: @MarkLinus "type"?  Sounds like you're pulling classical ideas into a far more dynamic space.  Relying on things like `instanceof` just bind you to misaligned paradigms in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm just saying that, though it's correct, your solution don't solves this problem I described: `new Human()`will not be an instance of class `Human` as expected

Comment: @MarkLinus You're answering with bias a question that wasn't asked.  Using `instanceof` like that is a form of programming to implementation.  Both objects provide the same functionality, and this solution begins by saying it is leaning in the `functional` direction which implies the object has more in common with data than a type system.

Comment: I know it wasn't, but this might be a problem in the future, since I don't know how the OP will use this class

Comment: Yes, if its thrown into a system that is written tied to implementation it will be one of the many bumps that are encountered and possibly invite kludges.

Comment: It is a **functional/parasitic** style constructor which is an alternative to the pseudo-classical style of using the `new` keyword.  It says this right before the code.  It is a common alternative that you should look into before arguing against.  It is far simpler and in my experience saves a lot of people with strong OO background from head scratching as to why things don't work like they seem they should with prorotypal inheritance.

Comment: That's OK, but I don't think you should mix the two approaches. At least, please explain the differences/drawbacks or link to a site that does it.

Comment: That's fine for you to think that but it's also attaching more impact to the use of `new` than actually exists.  If you plan on dealing with JS at length you should be comfortable with both.  I'd say you should also stop mentioning using `instanceof` with an implication that it could be used in enforcing a contract which is an invitation for poor design when applied to a classical hierarchy and brings a false sense of security with a language as dynamic as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer simply to complement the others, it SHOULD NOT be used unless you fully know the impact of using the non-standard `__proto__`.

```
function Monkey(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

function Human(name, age, cars) {
  this.__proto__ = new Monkey(name, age);
  this.cars = cars;
}

console.log(new Human(1, 2, 3));
```

**See also**

- [__proto__, when will it be gone? Alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476560/proto-when-will-it-be-gone-alternatives)
- [JavaScript and __proto__ - what browsers use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082791/javascript-and-proto-what-browsers-use-it)

Comment: Actually I don't think it should be used at all - the inheritance is weird :-)

Comment: @Bergi You mean the fact that humans inherit from monkeys? I agree :) Seriously though, the prototype structure doesn't strike me as unintuitive.

Comment: No. Every single human inherits from its own monkey. No human is `instanceof Human`, and `Human.prototype` is useless.

Comment: @Bergi That makes sense; but that's also due to the nature of the question itself in a way.