# Why the following code, `p.__proto__.aa` does not equal to 200?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Person(name,age){
    this.name = name
    this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.home = [1,2,3];
Person.prototype.aa =100;
var p = new Person('joy','7');


console.log(p.__proto__.home); //[1,2,3]
console.log(p.__proto__.aa); // 100

p.aa = 200; 
p.home[0] = 200; 

console.log(p.__proto__.home); //[200,2,3]
console.log(p.__proto__.aa); // 100
```

Why `p.__proto__.home` was changed. In my opinion, the `p.aa = 200;` has changed the `p.__proto__.aa`,but it was not.

Why know the reason? Please write more details.
Which book is relevant to the content?

Comment: `p.aa !== p.prototype.aa` <- those are two different things ?

Comment: p.home === p.prototype.home?

Comment: Not an answer, but isn't double underscore proto double underscore highl y discouraged (form wise)? I read that in a book.

Comment: @cresjoy: Yes it is. You should use `Object.getPrototypeOf(p).aa` instead.

Comment: Or maybe [Javascript object members that are prototyped as arrays become shared by all class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425318/1048572) would've been the better duplicate target. Any gold-bagder feel free to fix it.

Comment: @cresjoy It's also non-standard. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10476560/5743988)

Comment: @Bergi Also not a good close fit IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to *access* an attribute which does not exist on the object, Javascript will traverse up the prototype chain to find the attribute. However:

```
p.aa = 200
```

This assigns the attribute `aa` to the object directly. The object now as an attribute `.aa`, and it also still has `.__proto__.aa` **as two independent attributes**. You're not indirectly modifying the prototype by assigning to `.aa`.

Comment: basically var p  = {aa:200}, right with that line? we arent changing the prototype. (I'm not the op but just wondering)

Comment: Well, you are *replacing* the object outright, which means it's also losing its `__proto__`... Ignoring that detail, yes, that's what you're doing.

Comment: What do you mean losing __proto_?

Comment: You've just replaced the entire object by redefining `p` entirely. If it were `p.aa = 200` as in the OP's code, where the entire object isn't replaced, the fact that own properties added later won't overwrite properties already existing in the prototype chain is the issue

Comment: @cresjoy OP's `p` has `p.__proto__.aa`. When you do `p = {..}`, that new `p` now doesn't have `p.__proto__.aa`.

Comment: Really? Wow, I totally did not know that. I thougt p.aa = 200, just adds a property aa with key 200, and leaves everything as is

Comment: So is thee any way to keep the original proto, while adding in a property of aa?

Comment: @cresjoy I think we're talking past each other.

Answer (score 0):

`p.__proto__.home` has not been changed. The array that it references has been changed.